# Visual Studio: quickly check which projects in a solution are already built

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I notice an addin (VSBuildStatus extension) can meet my needs but it only supports up to VS2010, not VS2015.

My solution is a VC++ solution.

Basically, for any project I need a quick way to determine "Is this project built since the last code change?". The only way I know is by building (not "rebuild") it again. This is too slow under VS2015.

There must be a quicker way to check that. Basically, the IDE remembers which projects are already built.

I'm trying out Visual Studio 2015. In my earlier IDE (VS2008), project build is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

[BuildVision](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23d3c821-ca2d-4e1a-a005-4f70f12f77ba) extension supports newer versions of Visual Studio up to VS 2015.